# Bigcommerce use in an Iframe

Tags: iframe

A client has a large bigcommerece site and we are looking at showing the shopping cart within an iframe (so we can have add functionality over and above just a shopping cart).

At the moment the site is www.xxx.com and the home page is the cart.

So does using an Iframe screw up any of the google analytics or SEO that is already in place.

MrWarby

Answer (score 0):

You won't want to use an iFrame with a shopping cart, you'll get a lots of client side errors due to security. Additionally, you want get any SEO benefit for you main site.

I can't stress this enough, don't use an iFrame